# Stream peek() method behaviour

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
long result = nums
        .stream()
        .peek(System.out::print)
        .map(n->n*n)
        .filter(n->n>20)
        .peek(System.out::print)
        .count();
System.out.println(result);
```

Why shouldn't it print `12345625362` instead of `1234525362`?

Comment: The output is `12345256362`, not `1234525362`, there is a 6 between 25 and 36.

Comment: try to add space between numbers `.peek(i -> System.out.print(i + " "))` It will be helpful to understand what's going on

Answer (score 5):

If we add spaces inside the println in `peek` we can get a better idea of why this happens:

```
long result2 = nums.stream()
                   .peek(e -> System.out.print(e + " "))
                   .map(n->n*n)
                   .filter(n->n>20)
                   .peek(e -> System.out.print(e + " "))
                   .count();
```

This outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 25 6 36
```

As you can see `1` goes through, is printed out, does not pass the filter, and is thus the square is not printed. The same is true for `2`, `3`, and `4`. Then `5` goes through, and is printed. It passes the filter, so `25` is printed. So far we have :

```
1 2 3 4 5 25
```

Then six passes through in a similar fashion and we are left with

```
1 2 3 4 5 25 6 36
```

And then `System.out.println(result);` is printed. Since the last call was to `print` and not `println` it is printed on the same line, so a `2` is appended. If we take back out the spaces this yields:

```
12345256362
```

Which is the result

Answer (score 1):

All stream operations are first applied to 1, first `peek` / `print`, then `map` and then `filter`, removing the element. Same exact thing happens to 2, 3 and 4. The output afterwards is `1` `2` `3` `4`.

Then for 5 we `peek` / `print`, then `map`, `filter` leaving the element in tact and then `peek` / `print` the squared number. Output `5` `25`

Same thing for 6. Output: `6` `36`.

All together `1234` `525` `636` -> `1234525636`

And then a final `2` for the `count`.